# How can I properly store this byte value in memory?

Tags: assembly, memory, mips

I'm writing a simple looping program in MIPS for class but cannot get the "sb" instruction to work. I've run several benchmarks (output displayed below) which shows that the register I'm storing from contains its intended value, but that after "sb" the label representing its location in memory ("fahr1") does not. Program assembles and executes as intended except for this problem.

The integer value in "$t1" is obtained from a parent function from the user and is initialized properly as evidenced by the benchmark outputs below.

All code and output excerpts below (excepting the ".data" section of course) are from the same branch.

"sb" instruction line:

```
sb $t1, fahr1
```

Benchmark outputs:

```
VALUE OF $t1: 45
VALUE OF fahr1 AFTER 'sb $t1, fahr1' HAS EXECUTED: 0
VALUE OF $t0 AFTER 'lb $t0, fahr1' HAS EXECUTED: 0
DECIMAL ADDRESS IN MEMORY OF fahr1: 268501390
```

Relevant .data:

```
.data
fahr1: .byte
```

I'm working in MARS Mips and cannot find in the .data Segment after execution any address in memory location "268501390" (hex would be "100100C1"). Any suggestions on how to fix this or alternative ways of storing and retrieving unsigned integer numbers from memory?

(p.s. I'm storing as"byte" instead of "word" since for "byte" I don't have to complicate matters with alignment or offset; at least I don't think).

Comment: `fahr1: .byte`  is missing any operands, so you aren't reserving any bytes of memory for your "variable" after that label.  Maybe you meant `.byte 0`.  Use the MARS debugger to examine memory as you single-step your code.  There should be *some* byte that changes after the `fahr1:` label, even if you didn't reserve any.

Comment: @PeterCordes Not initializing my memory locations to 0 _was_ the problem. Thanks for helping an ASM noob like me! Very much appreciated.

Comment: `.byte` without a 0 isn't just "not initializing to zero", it's not even reserving any space.  i.e. `.byte` is zero-size.  You could write `.byte` in the middle of a function in your `.text` section and not mess up the machine code because it literally emits no bytes into the output when it has no operands.  `.byte 123, 1, 2, 3` would be fine, too, and emits 4 initialized bytes.